# libgdx - 3D grid generation

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

Hi, so I am using libgdx 1.9.6 to create a 3D grid using ModelBuilder. I need to however be able to edit each vertex in the grid space to work with OpenSimplex (Perlin noise).

I can create the gird just one time ([static grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5RR9.png)) but I run into the issue where constantly rendering it throws the frames down to 1 frame per-second because there is simply too much going on ([low frame grid being constantly updated](https://i.gyazo.com/74a49cf2a234ab554fe3398f1adc4b39.mp4)).

Here is the code I am using to get this output:

```
private PerspectiveCamera camera;
private ModelBatch modelBatch;              
private Model gridModel;                    
private ModelInstance gridInstance;

public void create(){
    camera = new 
    PerspectiveCamera(80,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    camera.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);

    camera.lookAt(0f,0f,0f);                
    camera.near = 0.1f;                     
    camera.far = 1000f;                     

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    gridLineColor = new Color(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    //createGrid();  //This was originally here but it needs to update
}
public void render(){
    camera.update();
    render(instances);
}
private void render(Array<ModelInstance> instances){
    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    createGrid();   //So it was moved here and being called 60 times per sec
    modelBatch.render(gridInstance);
    modelBatch.end();
}

private final float gridMin = -50f;
private final float gridMax = 50f;
private final float scale = 1f;

private void createGrid() {
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

    modelBuilder.begin();

    Random ran = new Random();
    float temp = ran.nextFloat();

    MeshPartBuilder builder = modelBuilder.part("gridpart1", GL20.GL_LINES, Usage.Position | Usage.ColorUnpacked, new Material());
    builder.setColor(gridLineColor);

    for(float z = gridMin; z < gridMax; z += scale){
        for(float x = gridMin; x < gridMax; x += scale){
            builder.line(x, temp, z, x+scale, temp, z);
        }
    }
            // So we add another part with a different id
    builder = modelBuilder.part("gridpart2", GL20.GL_LINES, Usage.Position | Usage.ColorUnpacked, new Material());
    for(float z = gridMin; z < gridMax; z += scale){
        for(float x = gridMin; x < gridMax; x += scale){
            builder.line(x, temp, z, x, temp, z+scale);
        }
    }
    gridModel = modelBuilder.end();

    gridInstance = new ModelInstance(gridModel);
}
```

So we add another part to the modelBuilder id labeled *gridpart2* because using just one creates an error saying **too many vertices**.

Now I know the grid just moves up and down but when I fully implement perlin noise each vertices of the grid will be able to flow freely as I am drawing each line connected to each point on the grid with the for loops. I am not sure what else I could use for this method that would speed up the process. Perhaps different solutions maybe using shaperender could work but I haven't looked too much into it.

The desired outcome of this is to be like *TheCodingTrain*'s example of 3D terrain generation using perlin noise.

Also I cannot change coding languages or environments to make things easier, I have to use Java as it is an assignment for class I took on for myself.

Comment: So the problem is `createGrid` is too slow?

Comment: Why are you calling `createGrid` every frame?

Comment: Is your grid supposed to fluctuate over time (like an ocean) or is it static?

Comment: In either case you should just be creating it once

Comment: I need to call create grid every frame to because every frame the grid should update the y value to a new position, and how that its updating currently is a random float between 0 and 1 which will soon be a perlin noise function.